# Post two images on Facebook with UWP Community Toolkit

Tags: facebook, windows-10-universal, windows-community-toolkit

Is there a way to post two images in a single post with UWP Community Toolkit?.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, you can check the [official sample app of UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp).

It has encapsulated the twitter apis in its service. And according to the Twitter developer documentation: [Uploading Media](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media.html), it is supported to upload maximum 4 photos in a tweet.

In a word, you can open the project of this sample app, and find **SamplePages** -> **Twitter Service** -> **TwitterPage.xaml.cs**, finally find the `SharePictureButton_OnClick` event and override the original code:

```cs
StorageFile picture = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (picture != null)
{
    using (var stream = await picture.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        await TwitterService.Instance.TweetStatusAsync(TweetText.Text, stream);
    }
}
```

to:

```cs
var pictures = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
int num = pictures.Count;
List<IRandomAccessStream> streams = new List<IRandomAccessStream>();
foreach (var picture in pictures)
{
    var stream = await picture.OpenReadAsync();
    streams.Add(stream);
}

await TwitterService.Instance.TweetStatusAsync(TweetText.Text, streams.ToArray());
```